# Excel, Stop update NOW(), when other cell changed value or string

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've in a single row of excel
Start Time, End Time, Duration & Status
[image]

[image]

End time is being calculated using NOW(), function of excel. I want this to be stop updating value. If status cell in the row is changed to Stop from Running.
This Stop is being done by manually.

Comment: Turn off automatic updating and update only the cells which need to be recalculated

Comment: This is very possible with VBA code, but please post what you have tried so we can help you get it working. (You know by now, I am sure, that SO is not a code for me site). If you have not tried anything, look into `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: This is also possible with circular formulas, but you need to allow and limit the iterations.

Comment: @akD Are you going to accept one of these answers?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution to this problem is to use drop-down lists with data validation. (This can be done without VBA.)

Data validation drop-down lists are always non-volatile, even if you choose a volatile value from the drop-down list.

Simple example that you can use to apply to your spreadsheet:

Assume cell `A1` contains the formula `= NOW()`, and that cell `B1` is set up with data validation in the following way:

[image]

Now cell `B1` will take a "snapshot" of `NOW()` whenever you choose the only available option from the drop-down list, and it will keep that value indefinitely until you reselect from the drop-down.

[image]

Any cells that need `NOW()` can instead just use `$B$1`, which is basically just `NOW()` but it is frozen in time until you reselect again from the drop-down list.

This is a sneaky way to convert a volatile cell to a non-volatile one (without using VBA).

Comment: Good answer. Worth pointing out that you only need one of these such dropdown cells in the spreadsheet, which you could assign a name to such as =CurrentDateTime, and then use that name in all the places you currently use =NOW(). To make it foolproof, you could then use VBA to update that cell every time the workbook is opened. Mind you, if using VBA, then better to just ditch the dropdown and update the cell value directly.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Agreed. I was primarily answering the question as an alternative to using VBA. But I agree that if you want to use VBA then the drop-down is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vba, Range("A1").Value = Now() is essentially the Now formula that runs only when the macro is triggered.

Of course, switch out Range("A1") with whatever cell you need the date. Without seeing your code I can't offer any suggestions. Personally I've used offset to select the paste location.