# Extracting data by date (today-function) but don't want data to change over time

Tags: excel, date, pivot-table, snapshot

I'm helping colleagues to extract data from a big table of info entered by week. The problem is that I want the date to be true at that moment and not the next month menaning that for a specific month the data should be extracted and not changed after that. My formula compares the date in a cell plus/minus a certain amount of given days and turnes this into a weeknumber. This is then compared with the sheet with all the data. So let's say that for end of October I need to extract the info from column F as the info looks in october. The info in column F is changed all through the year. So I want a snapshot of the data in October. Then next month I want a snapshot of the data in column F what it looks like in November.

My problem is that it changes for every month so when november comes, october becomes 0 and it only calculates for the current month. Since I use the today()-function I guess this is how it should work but I'd like the formula to only execute as the month is true and only once. Is this even possible?

I've been starting to think that I might need to create a macro but I didn't want to do this. However, it seems that this might be the only way?

Kind regards
David Albady

Comment: If you want to avoid VBA, use a drop-down list (in data validation) to "snapshot" a moment in time and store it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387962/excel-stop-update-now-when-other-cell-changed-value-or-string/48388905#48388905) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `TODAY()` in the function, you may use `=DATE($C$1,$D$1,$E$1)` . Where C1,D1,E1 is the year, month, day that you can manually define.

Hope that helps. ( :